# Compiler discrepancy with simple meta function

Tags: c++, c++17

When I try to use the following meta function to retrieve the first type of a tuple, the code can be compiled with GCC but not with Clang. I have two questions regarding the little snippet.

1. Is this legal C++ code? And why? Or why not?
2. Is there a workaround (or correct alternative) which works for both compilers?

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<typename>
struct first_type;

template<template<typename, typename...> typename T, typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct first_type<T<T1, Ts...>>
{ using type = T1; };

template<typename T>
using first_type_t = typename first_type<T>::type;

using tuple_type1 = first_type_t<std::tuple<int, int, double>>;
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/6qnf3oj7E)

---

As requested, the error message generated by Clang:

```
<source>:12:1: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
    'first_type<std::tuple<int, int, double>>'
using first_type_t = typename first_type<T>::type;
^
<source>:14:21: note: in instantiation of template type alias
    'first_type_t' requested here
using tuple_type1 = first_type_t<std::tuple<int, int, double>>;
                    ^
<source>:4:8: note: template is declared here
struct first_type;
       ^
```

---

In conclusion:

- As answered by IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes; to circumvent the compiler discrepancy completely, simply drop the requirement of the templated template argument to have at least a single type.
- As pointed out by Nathan Oliver; if you need the first type of a tuple (or really any type given an index), simply use the [std::tuple_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) meta function instead.
- As pointed out by HolyBlackCat; it seems the ruling that Clang enforces regarding templated template arguments, is stricter than technically required by the standard. This behavior can be disabled by passing the `-frelaxed-template-template-args` compiler flag.

Comment: When there's discrepancy, generally clang is right, MSVS wrong, and GCC will compile whatever you throw at it.

Comment: FWIW, you can use [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) instead like `using first_type_t = typename std::tuple_element<0, T>::type;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I completely overlooked that :D

Comment: Name in `template<typename T1, typename... Ts>class T` are not useful and is a little misleading as reused after.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, Jarod. I appreciate your advice and I've updated the initial question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporarily changing your struct declaration to (thus getting rid of the incomplete type):

```
template<typename>
struct first_type {};
```

Changes the error you get to:

```
no type named 'type' in 'first_type<std::tuple<int, int, double>>'
```

This gives us valuable information: the compiler chose the generic version of the template, implying that Clang does not consider tuple to be a valid `template<typename,typename...>class` to instantiate `first_type` with (which is true - `template<typename,typename...>class` takes one or more parameters, while a tuple can also be empty). As pointed out in the comments, this does not matter to the standard itself, but [Clang rejects it on purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238897/what-conversion-of-template-template-parameters-is-allowed-in-c).

A tuple is a `template<typename...>class`, so...

```
template<template<typename...> typename T, typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct first_type<T<T1, Ts...>> {
    using type = T1;
};
```

Comment: I guess you could change the primary template back to being incomplete now when you have fixed the specialization?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Is this a completion of my answer, or an edit suggestion?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Great insight! I didn't occur to me to even try this variantion and your explanation why this happens seems to make a lot of sense. The only thing still missing is a more formal statement that reveals why GCC should be producing an error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You posted a great answer as well that could be very useful for peeps like me who are still learning meta programming. I would be more than happy to upvote your answer if you post it again :)

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes The comment was just a suggestion to make it impossible to instantiate it.

Comment: @303 Thanks but does it really do what you asked for? My `first_type` would be better named `first_non_template_type` - if it had worked consistently. My `first_type_t<std::string, int>` is `std::string` but `first_type_t<std::string>` is `char`. :-)

Comment: Clang acceps this if you pass `-frelaxed-template-template-args`. Since this flag enables standard-compliant behavior which is disabled by default, GCC is actually right.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How odd that that flag isn't set by default in C++17/20 mode even in clang trunk 8-O

Comment: @TedLyngmo They say it's a breaking change, because something about the wording is defective. They're still waiting for a fix it seems. :/